# convert list to string using join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I was trying to convert the below **tags** column to normal string without the brackets and commas and tried the below two ways but I'm getting error.
can someone tell a correct way

[image]

Error: can only join an iterable

Comment: What is error here?

Comment: can only join an iterable @jezrael

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Do post the exact error message. Also, as a courtesy, providing the dataframe in `new.head().to_dict()` format or similar would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for informing, won't repeat this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are missing values and lists filled by strings, you can use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
new['tags'] = new['tags'].str.join(' ')
```

Or join only rows with no missing values:

```
m = new['tags'].notna()
new.loc[m, 'tags'] = new.loc[m, 'tags'].apply(' '.join)
```

If there are also non strings values in lists:

```
new = pd.DataFrame({'tags': [['In','ss',5], None]})
    
m = new['tags'].notna()
new.loc[m, 'tags'] = new.loc[m, 'tags'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(map(str, x)))
print (new)
        tags
0  In, ss, 5
1       None
```

Comment: It's converted to string but not removing the commas

Comment: @JutikaPatil - Can you change `', '.join` to `' '.join` ?